# How to segue from tab bar view controller to another view which is a child of a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I laid out my home screen (Summary screen) as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

I added the "+" button on the UITabBarController subclass. This button will segue to a view controller and show it modally. To give you a bit of context on how I've structured my storyboards, please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

This modal view controller has a form that the user needs to fill in, and once they're done, there's a 'Done' button which will 1) dismiss the modal, 2) take them back to the root view which is either the 'Summary' tab or the 'Details' tab then 3) take them to a list view showing the most recent data they've entered on a list (destination view – highlighted in red).

Now, doing the segue when the user taps the "+" button is simple enough. With the following code:"

`menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

then

```
func addNewExpense(action: UIAlertAction){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_formModal", sender: self)
}
```

On the modal I've setup a protocol which will then send the form data back to the tab view controller.

```
extension XtabBarViewController: NewInfoDelegate{
func newInfoSubmitted(formData: FormData) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_ListingPage", sender: self)
}
```

}

But it seems that the perform segue is not working. It says the segue does not exist. "segue_ListingPage" is that segue that connects the Summary view and the destination view.

How can I segue from the tab bar view controller to the destination view? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the navigation view controller the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. For the benefit of those who run into the same issue here's my solution.

I simply added the code from the tab bar view controller the code:

```
    let childVC = children[0].children[0]
    childVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_TXListPage", sender: self)
```

So what I did here is call the performSegue from the view controller that segues to the destination controller.